# Can JavaScript be broken into regions in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

C# code can be separated into regions by using the #region and #endregion tags.

Can the same be done for JavaScript code ?
I have a file with some 1100 lines and it's getting hard to manage it.

Comment: Perhaps break apart your `.JS` file into smaller files?  They can be included in each page, or combined into a single file through a build process.

Comment: Those are `C#` tags so probably not.  Instead, maybe break your JS file into multiple files and use a Module Pattern to work them together.  You can then later bring them all back together with an uglifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [Web Essentials extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f) for Visual Studio 2010.

From the features list:

[image]

However, it also might be best to start to break apart your JavaScript files into smaller files, or separate modules.  That way, you can only include the code relevant to a specific page.  If need be, those files can be combined again using a build tool such as [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you would have #region and #endregion for Javascript this would not solve your problem. You should focus on separating the whole logic into separate files and make that each JS file is responsible for a certain piece of work. Believe me - this will considerably improve the readability of your code and make it much more maintainable. 
I recommend to read this book (although it is not stricly about JS, but about writing in general):
[http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)